# Real-Time video stabilization with Kalman filter

Tags: opencv, video, homography

I've found this code https://github.com/Lakshya-Kejriwal/Real-Time-Video-Stabilization. But this code uses an affine transformation.

```
affine = estimateRigidTransform(goodFeatures1, goodFeatures2, false);

dx = affine.at<double>(0,2);
dy = affine.at<double>(1,2);
da = atan2(affine.at<double>(1,0), affine.at<double>(0,0));

smoothedMat.at<double>(0,0) = sx * cos(da);
smoothedMat.at<double>(0,1) = sx * -sin(da);
smoothedMat.at<double>(1,0) = sy * sin(da);
smoothedMat.at<double>(1,1) = sy * cos(da);

smoothedMat.at<double>(0,2) = dx;
smoothedMat.at<double>(1,2) = dy;

warpAffine(frame_1, smoothedFrame, smoothedMat, frame_2.size());
```

I need to do video stabilization with homography matrix. So I need to do

```
warpPerspective(frame_1, smoothedFrame, smoothedMat, frame_2.size());
```

But `warpPerspective` requires that the `smoothedMat` has a dimension 3*3.
I try to do this:

```
smoothedMat.at<double>(2,0) = 0;
smoothedMat.at<double>(2,1) = 0;
smoothedMat.at<double>(2,2) = 1;
```

But so I have an error:

```
error: (-215:Assertion failed) (M0.type() == 5 || M0.type() == 6) && M0.rows == 3 && M0.cols == 3 in function 'warpPerspective'.
```

How should I do this?

Comment: it says that `smoothedMat` is not CV_32F or CV_64F and the size is not (3x3). How is this matrix created? I see that you initialize it correctly, and probably the first condition is met (CV_64F), but not sure about the size unless you show the line where it was created

Comment: Thanks!!! Yes, I did not notice that the matrix is ​​declared so "smoothedMat.create(2 , 3 , CV_64F);"